# DataSet - RowChanged Event raised many Times?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dataset

I have this code :

```
this.hRAddNewDataSet.Employee.RowChanged += new DataRowChangeEventHandler(Employee_RowChanged);

    void Employee_RowChanged(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        test++;
        Trace.WriteLine(test.ToString());
    }
```

When I run my app and edit one row and then click the save button, the RowChanged event will fire 35 time!.
I know this because of the value for test var.

My Questions:

1. why this event fire like this?
2. How I can get the current column is
   being updated?

Comment: what about putting a breakpoint into the eventhandler and inspect e.Row, e.Action and the calltree in the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why this event fire like this?

Perhaps you are wiring up the event handler multiple times?

Or maybe some part of your code is changing the row multiple times?

> How I can get the current column is being updated?

Use the [ColumnChanged event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.columnchanged.aspx) and check the `DataColumnChangeEventArgs` parameter.